# Using JPA in a Javalin application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javalin

I am creating a web application in Java and would like to use the [Javalin](https://javalin.io/) framework.

Issues/questions:

- What would be the best way to use [JPA (via hibernate)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa) in a [Javalin](https://javalin.io/) web application?
- I.e. what is the best way make a JPA `EntityManager` object available to  the Javalin request handlers?

*Update: Some more context*

I want to use JPA (via Hibernate) in my javalin application. The central concept in JPA is that you use an `EntityManager` instance to access the database. To create an `EntityManager`, there is a `EntityManagerFactory`.

What I currently do is that I create a global `EntityManagerFactory` and the handlers that use the database call `factory.createEntityManager()`.

While this works, I wonder if there are other recommended apporaches? Coming from a Flask/SQLAlchemy/Python background - on that stack the ORM session (EntityManager equivalent) is typically available as a request-bound object.

Comment: Re. the close vote: The question is NOT about "please recommend which library/framework to use". The question is: What is the best way to combine library A and library B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing the following:

- Create an `EntityManagerFactory` on startup. Create a `Javalin` instance on startup. Then call `enableRequestBoundEntityManager(javalinApp, entityManagerFactory)`.
- Whenever a handler needs an `EntityManager`, use the extension property `Context.entityManager`.

I.e.:

```
fun main() {
    val app = Javalin.create()
    val emf = createEntityManagerFactorySomehow()

    enableRequestBoundEntityManager(app, emf)

    app.get("/list/") { ctx -> ctx.json(
        ctx.entityManager.createQuery("select ... from ...").resultList
    ) }

    app.start()
}

/**
 * Adds an `entityManagerFactory` application attribute, and sets up clean up after requests have been handled
 */
fun enableRequestBoundEntityManager(app: Javalin, entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory) {
    app.attribute("entityManagerFactory", entityManagerFactory)

    app.after {
        val entityManager: EntityManager? = it.attribute("entityManager")
        if (entityManager != null) {
            entityManager.close()
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a JPA entity manager scoped to the Javalin context
 */
val Context.entityManager: EntityManager
    get() {
        if (this.attribute<EntityManager>("entityManager") == null) {
            this.attribute("entityManager", this.appAttribute<EntityManagerFactory>("entityManagerFactory").createEntityManager())
        }
        return this.attribute("entityManager")!!
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this would make a good example/tutorial for javalin.io ? :)